# Connect to a FTP server using IPv6?

Tags: ipv6, ftp

Currently my device is running on Android 4.1.1 (JB). I have a FTP server with IPv6 address and connecting to it on my computer is just fine.

However when I try to connect to this server on my Android device (using AndFTP and Total Commander), the result is always "Network unreachable"

AFAIK, IPv6 support has been added to Android 4.0 or ICS. But I still don't know what's wrong with my device.

Can anybody tell me how can I fix it, or is there any way to track the problem?

Comment: To track the problem: yes. You could check the logcat for more error details, and what the device is doing. Having ADB available on your device (if not, see e.g. [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575)), this could be done using `adb logcat`.

Answer (score 1):

ICS has IPv6 support, but only on mobile data networks; it's somewhere between buggy and nonfunctional on Wi-Fi.

[Issue 3389 lists a wide variety of Android IPv6 bugs.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3389) Your issue is probably among them.

I've been using IPv6 successfully on my Verizon Droid RAZR MAXX since I got it almost a year ago, on ICS. Works great on 4G LTE. No idea what Jelly Bean does on Wi-Fi since I haven't gotten around to redoing my home network to bring IPv6 into every subnet yet...when I do, I'll be sure to update this.

[image]

Comment: That's really bad. It's my Android mini PC and I don't have mobile network connection, just WiFi and ethernet. Hope there will be a fix in the future for this.